# Компиляция QT на raspberry pi

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi

Имеется ПО, прекрасно работающее под WIN написано на QT, необходимо собрать ПО для rasberry pi, QT необходимо не ниже 5.12.5. Получилось собрать, но ПО запускается в полноэкранном режиме, как конфигурировать QT чтобы по работало в оконном режиме? Перепробовал различные варианты, по моему мнению включающие xcb, но натыкаюсь всегда на ошибку

'''

```
g++ -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--version-script,QtXcbQpa.version -Wl,-O1 -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-z,origin -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN -shared -Wl,-soname,libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 -o libQt5XcbQpa.so.5.12.7 .obj/qxcbclipboard.o .obj/qxcbconnection.o .obj/qxcbintegration.o .obj/qxcbkeyboard.o .obj/qxcbmime.o .obj/qxcbscreen.o .obj/qxcbwindow.o .obj/qxcbbackingstore.o .obj/qxcbwmsupport.o .obj/qxcbnativeinterface.o .obj/qxcbcursor.o .obj/qxcbimage.o .obj/qxcbxsettings.o .obj/qxcbsystemtraytracker.o .obj/qxcbeventqueue.o .obj/qxcbeventdispatcher.o .obj/qxcbconnection_basic.o .obj/qxcbconnection_screens.o .obj/qxcbatom.o .obj/qxcbdrag.o .obj/qxcbconnection_xi2.o .obj/qxcbsessionmanager.o .obj/qxcbglintegrationfactory.o .obj/qxcbglintegration.o .obj/qxcbnativeinterfacehandler.o .obj/qtessellator.o .obj/qpixmap_x11.o .obj/qpaintengine_x11.o .obj/qcolormap_x11.o .obj/qbackingstore_x11.o .obj/qxcbnativepainting.o .obj/qxcbvulkaninstance.o .obj/qxcbvulkanwindow.o .obj/moc_qxcbclipboard.o .obj/moc_qxcbconnection.o .obj/moc_qxcbmime.o .obj/moc_qxcbnativeinterface.o .obj/moc_qxcbsystemtraytracker.o .obj/moc_qxcbeventqueue.o .obj/moc_qxcbeventdispatcher.o .obj/moc_qxcbconnection_basic.o .obj/moc_qxcbglintegrationplugin.o  -L/opt/vc/lib /home/pi/qt-build/qtbase/lib/libQt5ServiceSupport.a /home/pi/qt-build/qtbase/lib/libQt5ThemeSupport.a /home/pi/qt-build/qtbase/lib/libQt5FontDatabaseSupport.a /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfontconfig.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so /home/pi/qt-build/qtbase/lib/libQt5LinuxAccessibilitySupport.a /home/pi/qt-build/qtbase/lib/libQt5AccessibilitySupport.a /home/pi/qt-build/qtbase/lib/libQt5VulkanSupport.a -lbrcmGLESv2 -lbrcmEGL /home/pi/qt-build/qtbase/lib/libQt5Gui.so /home/pi/qt-build/qtbase/lib/libQt5EdidSupport.a /home/pi/qt-build/qtbase/lib/libQt5DBus.so /home/pi/qt-build/qtbase/lib/libQt5Core.so -lpthread /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libX11-xcb.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libxcb.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libXrender.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libXext.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libX11.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libSM.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libICE.so /home/pi/qt-build/qtbase/lib/libxcb-static.a /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libxkbcommon-x11.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libxkbcommon.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so -lbrcmGLESv2 -lbrcmEGL /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgthread-2.0.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so
.obj/qxcbconnection.o:qxcbconnection.cpp:function QXcbConnection::QXcbConnection(QXcbNativeInterface*, bool, unsigned int, char const*): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbKeyboard::QXcbKeyboard(QXcbConnection*)'
.obj/qxcbconnection.o:qxcbconnection.cpp:function QXcbConnection::queryKeyboardModifiers() const: error: undefined reference to 'QXcbKeyboard::translateModifiers(int) const'
.obj/qxcbconnection.o:qxcbconnection.cpp:function QXcbConnection::handleXcbEvent(xcb_generic_event_t*): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbKeyboard::updateKeymap(xcb_mapping_notify_event_t*)'
.obj/qxcbconnection.o:qxcbconnection.cpp:function QXcbConnection::handleXcbEvent(xcb_generic_event_t*): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbKeyboard::updateXKBStateFromCore(unsigned short)'
.obj/qxcbconnection.o:qxcbconnection.cpp:function QXcbConnection::handleXcbEvent(xcb_generic_event_t*): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbKeyboard::updateXKBStateFromCore(unsigned short)'
.obj/qxcbconnection.o:qxcbconnection.cpp:function QXcbConnection::handleXcbEvent(xcb_generic_event_t*): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbKeyboard::updateXKBStateFromCore(unsigned short)'
.obj/qxcbconnection.o:qxcbconnection.cpp:function QXcbConnection::handleXcbEvent(xcb_generic_event_t*): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbKeyboard::updateXKBStateFromCore(unsigned short)'
.obj/qxcbconnection.o:qxcbconnection.cpp:function QXcbConnection::handleXcbEvent(xcb_generic_event_t*): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbKeyboard::handleKeyReleaseEvent(xcb_key_press_event_t const*)'
.obj/qxcbconnection.o:qxcbconnection.cpp:function QXcbConnection::handleXcbEvent(xcb_generic_event_t*): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbKeyboard::handleKeyPressEvent(xcb_key_press_event_t const*)'
.obj/qxcbconnection.o:qxcbconnection.cpp:function QXcbConnection::handleXcbEvent(xcb_generic_event_t*): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbKeyboard::updateXKBState(xcb_xkb_state_notify_event_t*)'
.obj/qxcbconnection.o:qxcbconnection.cpp:function QXcbConnection::handleXcbEvent(xcb_generic_event_t*): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbKeyboard::updateKeymap()'
.obj/qxcbconnection.o:qxcbconnection.cpp:function QXcbConnection::~QXcbConnection(): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbKeyboard::~QXcbKeyboard()'
.obj/qxcbintegration.o:qxcbintegration.cpp:function QXcbIntegration::possibleKeys(QKeyEvent const*) const: error: undefined reference to 'QXcbKeyboard::possibleKeys(QKeyEvent const*) const'
.obj/qxcbwindow.o:qxcbwindow.cpp:function QXcbWindow::handleXIEnterLeave(xcb_ge_event_t*): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbKeyboard::updateXKBStateFromXI(void*, void*)'
.obj/qxcbwindow.o:qxcbwindow.cpp:function QXcbWindow::handleButtonReleaseEvent(xcb_button_press_event_t const*): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbKeyboard::translateModifiers(int) const'
.obj/qxcbwindow.o:qxcbwindow.cpp:function QXcbWindow::handleMotionNotifyEvent(xcb_motion_notify_event_t const*): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbKeyboard::translateModifiers(int) const'
.obj/qxcbwindow.o:qxcbwindow.cpp:function QXcbWindow::handleButtonPressEvent(xcb_button_press_event_t const*): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbKeyboard::translateModifiers(int) const'
.obj/qxcbwindow.o:qxcbwindow.cpp:function QXcbWindow::handleXIMouseEvent(xcb_ge_event_t*, Qt::MouseEventSource): error: undefined reference to 'QXcbKeyboard::updateXKBStateFromXI(void*, void*)'
```

'''

Comment: попробуйте https://forum.qt.io/topic/97796/problem-build-qt-5-12-0-on-raspberry-pi-3/4

Comment: Расскажите подробнее какой вариант системы у вас запущен на raspberri pi. Если у вас не запущен какой нибудь GNOME и т.д. то приложение будет запускаться только в полноэкранном режиме. А так это плохо. Мне нра

Comment: Мне сложно сказать какой вариант системы запущен на raspberri pi(и я не могу залить другой вариант, ограничения разработки), но в оконном режиме другие программы на ней запускается, а вот собрать QT чтобы в итоге ПО компилилось для оконного режима не получается.

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev, меня смущает отключение xcb в предложенной конфигурации